# Java: Reusing vs Reallocating reference to container object?

Tags: java, performance, garbage-collection, time-complexity, hashset

**tl;dr:** In Java, which is better, reusing of container object or creating object every time and let garbage collector do the work

I am dealing with huge amount of data in Java where frequently I have following type of code structure:-

**Version1:**

```
for(...){//outer loop
   HashSet<Integer> test = new HashSet<>(); //Some container
   for(...){
      //Inner loop working on the above container Data Structure
   }
   //More operation on the container defined above
}//Outer loop ends
```

Here I allocated new memory every time in a loop and do some operations in inner/outer loop before allocating empty memory again.

Now I am concerned about the memory leaks in Java. I know that Java has a fairly good Garbage Collector but instead of relying on that should I modify my code as follows:-

**Version2:**

```
HashSet<Integer> test = null;
for(...){//outer loop
   if(test == null){
      test = new HashSet<>(); //Some container
   }else{
      test.clear()
   }
   for(...){
      //Inner loop working on the above container Data Structure
   }
   //More operation on the container defined above
}//Outer loop ends
```

I have three questions:-

1. Which will perform better, or there is no definitive answer.
2. Will second version will have more time complexity? In other other words is clear() function O(1) of O(n) in complexity. I didn't anything in javadocs.
3. This pattern is quite common, which version is more recommended one?

Comment: `clear` will probably be slightly faster (last time I checked by 10/15%). The best way is to test both approaches with your data. In a normal program, this is not going to be a bottleneck.

Comment: @assylias One reason I could think is that memory have to be resized everytime If I allocate fresh memory every time. but what about space complexity? If speed is not the concern will there will be significant impact on the memory footprint?

Comment: @TagirValeev Pardon me, I as quite absent minded there. I intended null check, If the container has never been initialized, I would give the memory else I would just clean and reuse the space I have got

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To my opinion it's better to use the first approach. Note that `HashSet.clear` never shrinks the size of hash-table. Thus if the first iteration of the outer loop adds many elements to the set, the hash-table will become quite big, but on the subsequent iterations even if much less space is necessary if won't be shrinked.

Also first version makes the further refactoring easier: you may later want to put the whole inner loop into the separate method. Using the first version you can just move it together with `HashSet`.

Finally note that for garbage-collection it's usually easier to manage short-lived objects. If your `HashSet` is long-lived, it may be moved to old generation and removed only during the full GC.

Comment: Thanks, Refactoring is interesting. But  about the size, after clear, next elements will be overwritten in the already expanded space. It will save time as re-sizing is quite costly in containers and maximum size will be max(all iteration)

Comment: @MangatRaiModi, if you can estimate in advance how many elements you need, just pass a parameter to `HashSet` constructor to avoid rehashing.

Comment: I thought about it, but its really hard as elements are added to the Hashset subject to various conditions, Is it a bad practice to over commit based on estimate?

Comment: @MangatRaiModi, As always it's a tradeoff. If you overestimate, you will take more memory than necessary, but will not need to rehash. If you underestimate, you will need to rehash, but consume less memory.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend you to stick to the first variant. The main reason behind this will be keeping the scope of your HashSet variable as small as possible. This way you actually ensure that it will be eligible for garbage collection after the iteration has ended. Promoting it's scope may cause other problems - the reference can be later used to actually change the state of the object.

Also, most modern Java compilers will produce the same byte code if you are creating the instance inside or outside the loop.

Comment: *most modern Java compilers will produce the same byte code if you are creating the instance inside or outside the loop.* . +1 for this line :)

Answer (score 3):

I think it's simpler to create a new HashSet each time, and likely to be less prone to refactoring errors later on. Unless you have a good reason to resuse the HashSet (Garbage Collection pauses are an issue for you, and profiling shows this part of the code is the cause) - I would keep things as simple as possible and stick to 1. Focus on maintainability, [Premature Optimization](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization) should be avoided.

Answer (score 1):

Which one is faster?. Actually the answer could vary depending on various factors.

Version-1 advantages :

> 1. Predictive branching at processor level might make this faster.
> 2. Scope of instance is limited to the first loop. If reference doesn't escape, JIT might actually compile your method. GC's job will
>      probably be easier.

Version -2 :

> 1. Less time in creation of new *containers* (frankly, this is not too much).
> 2. `clear()` is  `O(n)`
> 3. Escaped reference might prevent JIT from making some optimizations.

Which one to choose?. *measure performance for both versions several times*. Then if you find *significant difference*, change your code, if not, don't do anything :)

Comment: clear being O(n) is pretty bad, I thought Java would have some flag like: in use/dump. I guess I would better stick with version1. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @MangatRaiModi - Yes, unfortunately, for `clear()` you will have to each cell of the *container* and set it to `null` (what if you have leaked references?). So it is `O(n)`. I have a feeling that version 1 would be faster :)

Comment: Oops, didn't thought about leaked references, I was only thinking about primitive data types. So, it has to be O(n).

Answer (score 0):

Version 2 is better 
   but it will take little bit of more time but memory performance will be good

Comment: Some explanation would really help!

Comment: I don't think version 2 will be faster *madamji* :). In fact it is incorrect to assume that one version would be faster than the other. Depending on the JVM (JIT) , underlying system architecture, one version could be faster on one system but slower on another :)

Comment: @TheLostMind Frustrated Indian spotted :p [Off Topic]

Comment: @MangatRaiModi - Frustrated?. Who and Why exactly?

Comment: @TheLostMind , Sirji I have written there that its not faster but memory performance will be effective

Comment: @ShivaniGupta - Actually in version 2 memory performance is *bad* as reference is declared outside the outer loop :)

Answer (score 0):

It depends.

Recycling objects *can* be useful in tight loops to eliminate GC pressure. Especially when the object is too large for the young generation or the loop runs long enough for it be tenured.

But in your particular example it's it may not help much because a hashset still contains node objects which will be created on inserting and become eligible for GC on clearing.

On the other hand, if you put so many items into the set that its internal `Object[]` array has to be resized multiple times and becomes too large for the young generation then it might be useful to recycle the set. But in that case you should be pre-sizing the set anyway.

Additionally objects that only live for the duration of a code block *may* be eligible for object decomposition/stack allocation via [escape analysis](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/vm/performance-enhancements-7.html#escapeAnalysis). The shorter their lifetime and the less complex the code-paths touching those objects the more likely it is for EA to succeed.

In the end it doesn't matter much though until this method actually becomes an allocation hotspot in your application, in which case it would show up in profiler results and you could act accordingly.